# toggle switch by adding and removing Class with Jquery

Tags: jquery, svg, toggle, addclass, removeclass

I'm trying to make a toggle switch and I can not use toggleClass because with #bar1 I'm using SVG. With SVG I read that I have to use Attributes instead of addClass(). My idea is to click on a div to add a new class and remove the current class. The first click of the code works but I am unable to revert back to the original class with the second click. Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong?

```
$(".hamburger-container").click(function() {
  $("#bar1").attr('class', 'bar1');
  $(this).addClass('toggle');
  $(this).removeClass('hamburger-container');
});

$(".toggle").click(function() {
  $("#bar1").removeAttr('class', 'bar1');
  $(this).addClass('hamburger-container');
  $(this).removeClass('toggle');
});
```

The HTML

```
     <div class ="pull-right hamburger-container">

               <svg enable-background="new 0 0 32 32" height="32px" id="hamburger" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g id="Menu"><path class ="bar" id="bar1" d="M1,7h30c0.552,0,1-0.448,1-1c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1H1C0.448,5,0,5.448,0,6C0,6.552,0.448,7,1,7z" fill="#121313"/><path class="bar" id="bar2" d="M31,15H1c-0.552,0-1,0.448-1,1c0,0.552,0.448,1,1,1h30c0.552,0,1-0.448,1-1C32,15.448,31.552,15,31,15z" fill="#121313"/><path class="bar" id="bar3" d="M31,25H1c-0.552,0-1,0.448-1,1c0,0.552,0.448,1,1,1h30c0.552,0,1-0.448,1-1C32,25.448,31.552,25,31,25z" fill="#121313"/></g><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/><g/></svg>
            </div>
```

The CSS

```
      .toggle {
     width: 50px;
     height: 30px;
     display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1200;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-right: 20px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     }

   .hamburger-container {
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
    z-index: 1020;
     cursor:pointer;
      margin-right: 20px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     }
```

Comment: can you post the HTML, the answer has to do with the anchor of the event handlers, do you have a "wrapper" element on the `.hamburger-container` element for instance?  Is it wrapped in a `div` or something?

Comment: I would suggest a third class used only to apply the events. I think you also only need one click event. Inside there, you can use `.toggleClass('toggle')` and `.toggleClass('hamburger-container')` (removes if present, adds if missing).

Comment: I added the HTML and CSS.  It seems like .hamburger-container class is being removed but upon second click the first click event is firing again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anchor your event handler to some element that wraps.

Note that you remove the class you have it anchored to so once that happens the anchor of the click event handler is removed.

Example:  Using single handler anchored to the `pull-right` class

```
$(".pull-right").on("click", function() {
  var me = $(this);
  if (me.hasClass('hamburger-container')) {
    $("#bar1").attr('class', 'bar1');
    me.addClass('toggle');
    me.removeClass('hamburger-container');
  } else {
    $("#bar1").removeAttr('class', 'bar1');
    me.addClass('hamburger-container');
    me.removeClass('toggle');
  }
});
```

Note, use the closest static "wrapper" of the element (not body or document if at all possible) referenced by `".hamburger-container"` and `".toggle"`; like a `div`

Simpler CSS:

```
.hamburger-container,
.toggle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.toggle {
  z-index: 1200;
}
.hamburger-container {
  z-index: 1020;
}
```

Test it out here:  Note open console to see the log https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/tp5y8j1m/

Comment: Thank you both,  Both of these options helped out.

Comment: Yes I agree, there are viable points to both solutions and no "wrong" answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some markup that starts out like:

```
<div class="hamburger-container">stuff</div>
```

I think you can simplify your JavaScript down to a single click event handler if you simply add one more class to identify your element (e.g. "toggle-element"):

```
<div class="toggle-element hamburger-container toggle">stuff</div>
```

Now bind to the element via `toggle-element`:

```
$(".toggle-element").click(function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    if ($self.attr('class') !== undefined) {
        $self.removeAttr('class');
    } else {
        $self.attr('class', 'bar1');
    }
    $self.toggleClass('toggle hamburger-container');
});
```